# How to update View of parent Viewcontroller after a modal Viewcontroller is dimissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that i want to update from the value of a modal viewController when its been dismissed.At the moment i can only do it by getting the current visible viewController which is what i don't want. Is there a way i update the parent viewController after dismissing the modal one.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var accountButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ pAnimated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(pAnimated)
        self.accountButton.title = User.current!.firstName
   }

@IBAction func accountButton(_ pSender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let editUserAccountVC = UIStoryboard.fs_instantiateFromStoryboard("Main", identifier: "EditUserAccountViewController") as! EditUserAccountViewController
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editUserAccountVC)
        navVC.view.tintColor = self.view.tintColor
        self.present(navVC, animated: true)
       }
   }
}
```

This is the modal that is dismissed after editing

```
class EditUserAccountViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstName: String?

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let thePresentedViewController = self.presentingViewController as? HomeViewController {
                thePresentedViewController.accountButton.title = self.firstName
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: yes use protocol(delegate)

Comment: Check this answer by @valosip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677831/delegation-to-pass-data-back-from-modally-presented-view-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should store a reference to the parent controller in the modal controller instance. You can made it more generic with protocols. Declare the following `protocol`:

```
protocol AccountButtonProvider: AnyObject {
    var accountButtonTitle: String? { set get }
}
```

`AnyObject` is required to declare a reference to `AccountButtonProvider` as `weak`. I guess you will need it to avoid memory leaks.

Make `HomeViewController` conform to `AccountButtonProvider`:

```
extension HomeViewController: AccountButtonProvider {
    var accountButtonTitle: String? {
        set {
            accountButton.title = newValue
        }
        get {
            return accountButton.title
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the following property to `EditUserAccountViewController`:

```
weak var accountButtonProvider: AccountButtonProvider?
```

Initialise this property before you present `EditUserAccountViewController`. To do it add `editUserAccountVC.accountButtonProvider = self` to `accountButton(_:)`:

```
@IBAction func accountButton(_ pSender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let editUserAccountVC = UIStoryboard.fs_instantiateFromStoryboard("Main", identifier: "EditUserAccountViewController") as! EditUserAccountViewController
    editUserAccountVC.accountButtonProvider = self
}
```

You should also modify `saveButton(_:)`:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.accountButtonProvider?.actionButtonTitle = self.firstName
    }
}
```

All code in this post was tested in Xcode 10.2.1. I used Swift 5.

Comment: `HomeViewController` is the vc i'm going to. Why would i want to instatiate it and present it?

Comment: @sk123 Could you please add the code where you present `EditUserAccountViewController` instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **`closure`** to solve your problem statement.

**1.** Create a `closure` in `EditUserAccountViewController`

```
var handler: ((String?)->())?
```

**2.** Set the value of this `closure` when `EditUserAccountViewController` is presented from `HomeViewController`

```
controller.handler = {(name) in
    self.accountButton.title = name
}
```

**3.** Call the `closure` when `EditUserAccountViewController` is dismissed on pressing `saveButton`

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.handler?(self.firstName)
}
```

**Compiled code:**

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var accountButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func openEditUserAccountVC(_ sender: Any) {
        if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditUserAccountViewController") as? EditUserAccountViewController {
            controller.handler = {(name) in
                self.accountButton.title = name
            }
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class EditUserAccountViewController: UIViewController {
    var firstName: String?
    var handler: ((String?)->())?

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.handler?(self.firstName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `HomeViewController` is the vc i'm going to. Why would i want to instatiate it and present it?

Comment: This is just a way to solve the problem. You can obviously use whatever controllers you want.

Comment: I only want to uppdate the UIBarbuttonItem one the EditVC is dismissed

Comment: This is what is happening in the above code. `HomeViewController` presents `EditUserAccountViewController` and set the handler in`EditUserAccountViewController` which is called when `EditUserAccountViewController` is dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a delegate design pattern. Its easy and understandable.